# Problema con cuenta regresiva

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer una cuenta regresiva. Pensaba que la lógica estaba bien, pero parece que no funciona. Consiste en una cuenta regresiva que, al llegar la fecha deseada, se le añada automáticamente 1 día y el contador comienza de nuevo... pero por lo que parece no comienza de nuevo. ¿Alguna ayuda? Muchas gracias por adelantado.

```
        <html> 
        <head> 
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"> 

        var futuro = new Date (2018,9,22,20,02); //año, mes-1, dia, hora, minutos  
        var actualiza = 1000; 
        function faltan()
        { 
            var ahora = new Date(); 
            var faltan = futuro - ahora; 
            if (faltan > 0){ 
            var segundos = Math.round(faltan/1000); 
            var minutos = Math.floor(segundos/60); 
            var segundos_s = segundos%60; 
            var horas = Math.floor(minutos/60); 
            var minutos_s = minutos%60; 
            var dias = Math.floor(horas/24); 
            var horas_s = horas%24; 
            document.formulario.reloj.value= dias + " dias : " + horas_s + " horas : " + 
            +minutos_s + " minutos : " + segundos_s + " segundos" ; 
            setTimeout("faltan()",actualiza); 
        } 
        else //SI LA FECHA YA HA LLEGADO...
        { 

            var futuro = new Date();
            futuro.setHours(futuro.getHours()+24); //...LE SUMAMOS 1 DÍA (EN HORAS) A LA HORA ACTUAL Y...

            var actualiza = 1000; 
            function faltan() //...VOLVEMOS A COMENZAR LA CUENTA REGRESIVA
            { 
                var ahora = new Date(); 
                var faltan = futuro - ahora; 
                if (faltan > 0){ 
                var segundos = Math.round(faltan/1000); 
                var minutos = Math.floor(segundos/60); 
                var segundos_s = segundos%60; 
                var horas = Math.floor(minutos/60); 
                var minutos_s = minutos%60; 
                var dias = Math.floor(horas/24); 
                var horas_s = horas%24; 
                document.formulario.reloj.value= dias + " dias : " + horas_s + " horas : " + 
                +minutos_s + " minutos : " + segundos_s + " segundos" ; 
                setTimeout("faltan()",actualiza); 
            }

            document.formulario.reloj.value= "0 dias : 0 horas : 0 minutos : 0 segundos" ; 
            return true; 
        } 
        } 
        </script>
        </head> 
        <BODY onload="faltan()"> 
        <form name="formulario"> 
        <input type="text" name="reloj" value="" size="55" style="border : 0px ; text-align : center"> 
        </form> 
        </body> 
        </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un par de errores en tu codigo, estás declarando dos veces la función `faltan`, una dentro de la otra. Otro pequeño detalle es que cuando calculas los días lo haces utilizando la variable `horas` cuando deberías hacerlo con `horas_s`. La solución que te propongo es reestructurar dicha función de la siguiente forma:

```js
var futuro = (new Date (2017, 10, 25, 15, 48, 10)).getTime();
var actualiza = 1000;

function faltan() {
  var ahora = (new Date()).getTime();
  var faltan = futuro - ahora;

  if (faltan > 0){
    var segundos = ~~( faltan / 1000 );
    var minutos = ~~( segundos / 60 );
    var horas = ~~( minutos / 60 );
    var dias = ~~( horas / 24 );

    var segundos_s = segundos % 60;
    var minutos_s = minutos % 60;
    var horas_s = horas % 24;
    var dias_s = ~~( horas_s / 24 );

    document.formulario.reloj.value = [
   dias_s,
   "dias :",
   horas_s,
   "horas :",
   minutos_s,
   "minutos :",
   segundos_s,
   "segundos"
 ].join(' ');
 
 setTimeout("faltan()",actualiza);
 
  } else {
    futuro = new Date();
    futuro.setHours(futuro.getHours()+24);
    document.formulario.reloj.value = "0 dias : 0 horas : 0 minutos : 0 segundos";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Timer Javascript </title>
  </head>
  <body onload="faltan()"> 
    <form name="formulario"> 
      <input type="text" name="reloj" value="" size="55" style="border : 0px ; text-align : center"> 
    </form> 
  </body> 
</html>
```